# Unable to close the Mat dialog from NGRX Effect by problematically

Tags: angular, ngrx

Please help me here is the my code snippet. i am able to close the dialog from component itself. but not from the effect. iam using material 8.2 version.

```
userAddedSuccess$ = createEffect(() => {
        return this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(fromUserActions.addUserSuccess),
            tap(() => {
                this.dialogRef.close(true);
            }));
      }, {dispatch: false});
```

Comment: apart from the fact, that it's not a great idea to access your controller in an effect (your controller should trigger effects through actions) the problem may be that at the time of execution of your effect, `dialogRef` is not defined. All this is hard to tell without an error message or a more detailled description of what happens. did you debug? - if you need an effect to update your component it should always go through the state in the store: effect triggers action -> triggers reducer -> changes state -> triggers selector -> modifies controller

Comment: The reason why i need this, because i need to close the dialog after form submitted successfully inside the model. If not want to show the error msg inside the dialog. Suggest me any of the better idea.

Comment: With error message I meant what’s going wrong? Anything visible on the console with your current setup or does it just silently not work?

The improvement would be for the addUserSuccess Action to trigger a reducer that sets a flag in the store which you listen to in your component through a selector. Once the Observable provided by the selector fires, you call the code to close the dialog